# Number of $0$ in great number

Tags: arithmetic

For example,  $11111111111111100$ ends with  $2$ zeros ,when we did know the decimal representation like $100!$ also.

I would like a justified  answer for the following question . How many $0$ are in the end of decimal representation of $ 100!$?
Is there  a general process to know this number for greater number like $2^{100!}\times5^{39!}$?

Comment: $2^{100!}$ does not end in zero because it is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: yes i just make a typo

Comment: $2^{100!}*5^{39!}$ isn't very different, there are less 5 than 2 in its factorization so it ends with $5^{39!}$ zeros

Answer (score 4):

It is fairly easy with factorials, a number ends with as many $0$s as the number of $5*2$ in his factorization.
It is obvious that there are more 2 than 5 in the factorization of any factorial so we only need to count how many $5$s are there in the factorization of $100!$.
These are $\frac{100}{5}+\frac{100}{5^2}=24$ since $5^3>100$

Answer (score 1):

A very useful result to know, which also helps here, is Legendre's Theorem :

> The number $n!$ contains the prime factor $p$ exactly $$\sum_{k\geq 1} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor$$

Answer (score -1):

Of the 100 numbers multiplying to give 100! ten of them end in 0 (10, 20, ...100) giving 11 zeros. The only other way to get a 0 is to mutliply an even number by a number ending in 5. There are ten numbers ending in 5 (5, 15,...,95) and multiplying by any ten even numbers (except the multiples of 10) will give 10 more zeros. So that is 21 zeros on the end of 100!

Comment: This is not correct. See Alessandro's answer.

Comment: Yes, 50, 25 and 75 contribute two 5's which can be multiplied by even numbers to contribute 3 more zeros.

Comment: Also, $100!$ is "small" enough to calculate it and then simply count how many $0$s are there at the end of $93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000$